# I am using 2 cameras, astra and kinect for mapping. Could someone tell how to run rtabmap for both the cameras simultaneously?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, freenect-launch, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need maps of both the cameras simultaneously. As soon as I run rtabmap in another terminal, the first process dies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296612/i-am-using-2-cameras,-astra-and-kinect-for-mapping.-could-someone-tell-how-to-run-rtabmap-for-both-the-cameras-simultaneously-?/) by [Aniket_Gujarathi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36245/aniket_gujarathi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Open launch file named rtabmap.launch
2. change
3. now copy rtabmap.launch file in the same path and rename it as rtabmap2.launch and agin edit it
4. change
5. now launch 2 different launch file
   or

add namespace:=rtabmap2 and databse_path:= ~/.ros/rtabmap2.db
at the end of launch command

---

Originally posted by [elite_up](https://answers.ros.org/users/36316/elite_up/) with karma: 26 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aniket_Gujarathi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36245/aniket_gujarathi/) on 2018-07-07**:
Thank u...... This worked for me

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-07**:
@Aniket_Gujarathi if this solved your problem then please click the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-07-07**:
You may need to set `map_frame_id` (default `map`) and `vo_frame_id` (default `odom`) if you don't want the two rtabmap nodes and the two visual odometry nodes to publish on the same TF frames. `frame_id` should be also set differently between the cameras.